# REVERSE_WORD in c using pointers

Tags: c

i have tried this code but no output and there's no errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(char *p,char *v,int size){
    for(int i=size-1,j=0;i<0;i--){
        *(v+j) = *(p+i);
        j++; 
    }
}
int main(){
    char word[6] = {"hello"};
    char re_word[6];
    re_word[5]='\0';
    reverse(word,re_word,6);
    printf("%s",re_word);
}
```

Comment: BTW: it is a good habit/convention to make the destination pointer the first argument to the function, just like `memcpy()` and `str[n]cpy()` do. Also: use descriptive names for the arguments e.g `void reverse( char *dst, char *src, size_t siz);`

Comment: I recommend learning how to use the debugger, even when the result is apparently correct, and stepping into your code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointers it can look like this:

```
void reverse(char *w, char *revw, int slen) {

    revw += slen - 1;   // forward to pos. of last letter
    revw[1] = '\0';     // one further *(revw+1) 
    while (*w)
        *revw-- = *w++; 
}
```

This is clear and symmetric, once it works, while your `i--` and `j++` are far apart.

`slen` is meant to be the number of letters w/o termination. Here the call:

```
char word[] = {"hello"};
char re_word[sizeof word];
reverse(word, re_word, sizeof word - 1);
```

`strlen()` should be used, probably, but these lines show how you can and have to control not just the total size but especially the last byte of the char array.

Without the correct length, `reverse()` would have to do a `strlen()` first, because it has to know how far away to put the first letter.

This `*(v+j) = *(p+i)` is more or less `v[j] = p[i]` and does not really take advantage of pointers, on the contrary.

```
(revw
caller)                in reverse() 
 |                          |
 v                          v

-4    -3     -2     -1     revw     +1

o      l      l      e       h      \0

             ...    revw--        revw[1]
```

So `revw` is maybe not the best name inside the function; `revw_first_backwards` is meant...or `fill_start`. But before I fill backwards I do the one additional write to the right side to terminate the string: array notation using a pointer: `revw[1] = '\0'`.

Comment: You can compact the function body by `for(revw += slen, *revw-- =0; *w;       ) { *revw-- = *w++; }`

Comment: yes, but then how you place the comments? And worse: symmetry! (that `for`, or rather `,`  does a bit too much at the beginning). A compact function is good, a compact loop also. But good variation!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `i < 0` will always be false, given `i = size - 1` `>` `0`.

What you want is `i >= 0`.

Also, given `size = 6`, `size - 1` will be equal to 5, and that is the NULL terminator position since array indexing in C start from 0. Perhaps use a C function such as `strlen()` to calculate the length rather than hard coding it.

```
void reverse(char *p, char *v, size_t size)
{
    for (int i = size - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        *(v + j) = *(p + i);
        j++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[6] = {"hello"};
    char re_word[6];

    re_word[5] = '\0';

    reverse(word, re_word, 5); /* or reverse(word, re_word, strlen(word)) */
    printf("%s", re_word);
}
```